# I was {this close} to slapping him

Tags: phrase-usage

I came across the following sentence: (capitalization not mine)

> I was THIS CLOSE to slapping him.

I would expect a sentence like this one to be spoken rather than written since "this close" needs to be accompanied by a hand gesture like holding two fingers close together to indicate a small space.
What I'm not sure of is whether "this close" is commonly used in writing.

Comment: I don't have statistics to quote, so I'll avoid a full answer, but I don't know what you mean by "commonly." You're quoting an example that was written. I've read the phrase in written dialog and I wouldn't think twice about using it in, for example, an email. It doesn't require a hand gesture as it implies something narrow, a near miss, an almost something. Native speakers have no trouble comprehending the idiom. Do you have a specific question to ask? Does the idiom not make sense?

Comment: Written how? In a narrative (telling a story) it would be absolutely ok. The gesture would be assumed to be there. As straight writing, it could be "I was really/so CLOSE to slapping him."

Comment: Thanks for your replies. If someone wrote to me: "[something] is this high" I would think the sentence was ambiguous because "this" doesn't give a clear idea how high that thing is. Similarly, I assumed that "I was this close to doing something" would be unlikely to be encountered in a text.
Knowing that "this close" is an idiom and that the hand gesture is implied answers my question. Thanks again JBH and user3169.